# "IF" formula in excel using multiple conditions

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I need help with an "IF" formula in excel using multiple conditions.  This is what I need:

`IF (cell) is <201, then *$2, if (cell) is 201-400, then *$1.15, if (cell) is >400, then *$1)`

I am trying to create a "settlement" spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
=IF(A1<201,"2",IF(AND(A1>201,A1<400),"1.15",1))
```

However, you've not mentioned what do you want to do when cell value is 201. If you want it to result in `$2` then change formula to `A1<=201` or else if you want it to result in `$1.15` then write `A1>=201` and same aplies to 400.

***EDIT :***

```
=IF(A1<=200,"2",IF(AND(A1>200,A1<=400),"1.15",1))
```

Answer (score -1):

How many IF statements are you needing to string together?  You are on the right track, they just get confusing the more you need to string together.

Comment: Make sure that you have a logical order so you do not prematurely populate the field with data that also meets a condition ins a future IF statement and then make sure that you have enough closing brackets (Excel will color them to match the starting one, so once your first bracket highlights you shoul dbe good. =IF(B6=A1,B1,IF(B6=A2,B2,IF(B6=A3,B3,99)))