# How to convert this condition to an excel function ..?

Tags: excel

Please, I need to write this condition in excel as a function  :

```
if( A1 = 2 AND A2= 3 ) then { A3 will equal 10}
  else if( A1 = 4 AND A2= 5 ) then { A3 will equal 20} 
  else if ( A1 = 6 AND A2= 7 ) then { A3 will equal 30}
```

- A1, A2, A3 are the excel cells

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? also: what happens if none of the conditions are met?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["IF" formula in excel using multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384879/if-formula-in-excel-using-multiple-conditions)

Comment: ...or perhaps [IF Function with 3 conditions and outcomes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901388/if-function-with-3-conditions-and-outcomes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some boolean logic:

```
=((a1=2)*(a2=3)*10)+((a1=4)*(a2=5)*20)+((a1=6)*(a2=7)*30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the formula in A3:

```
=IF(AND(A1=2,A2=3),10,IF(AND(A1=4,A2=5),20,IF(AND(A1=6,A2=7,30,"NOT ANY OF THE CHOICES")))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a literal interpretation, this formula matches what you're looking for:

```
=IF(AND(A1=2,A2=3),10,IF(AND(A1=4,A2=5),20,IF(AND(A1=6,A2=7),30,"invalid values")))
```

However, using a lookup table might be better, like so:

[image]

The lookup table is in columns E:G, and then the formula in cell A3 is (adjust the table ranges as necessary to account for all value combinations):

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$4,MATCH(A1&A2,INDEX($E$2:$E$4&$F$2:$F$4,),0))
```